# Calculate correlation from paired t test's results

Tags: correlation, t-test, effect-size

I have the degrees of freedom, difference between means, 95% confidence interval, and p-value of a paired t-test (i.e., a t-test run to analyze pre-post scores). I need to calculate the corresponding correlation coefficient (r).

Do you know any reference indicating how to do so?

Comment: A dependent t-test = a paired t test? The original data is in format (X,Y). Now you have means of D=X-Y, CI of this mean, a p value for testing E(D) = 0, one df. You do not have Variance of X and Y. You want to have r between X and Y. I think it is impossible unless I misunderstood your information or you have more information.

Comment: Could you explain what a "dependent" t-test is?  For *some* versions of t-tests, but not all of them, enough information can be recovered to compute $r.$